# What conditions have to be met for a subset $A$ of a measurable set $X$ to be also measurable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

What conditions have to be met for a subset $A$ of a measurable set $X$ to be also measurable?
I understand that the union of measurable of sets is also measurable. But I am wondering if there is something about subsets of a measurable set. Are there any theorems regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a measure on  a sigma field only. The subsets of $X$, that belong to the sigma-field are then measurable.